# Angular 6 - differentiate between literal and parametrized route

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I'm facing a weird issue and I'm not sure how to handle it. I have an application which lets you either view your public account or create a new one.

Account and CreateAccount are standalone modules lazy loaded in routes.ts file.

```
export const routes: Array<Route> = [
  { path: '', component: WelcomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: ':name', loadChildren: './account/account.module#AccountModule' },
  { path: 'create-account', loadChildren: './create-account/create-account.module#CreateAccountModule', pathMatch: 'full'},  
  { path: '**', redirectTo: ''}
];
```

In order to show your account, you have to enter your user name and after that you are navigated to overview of your account. URL after this step should look like this: `https://baseurl.com/*accountName*/*someView*`

Account module routes look like this:

```
export const routes: Array<Route> = [
  { path: '', component: AccountComponent, canActivateChild: [AccountGuardService], children: [
    { path: '', component: OverviewComponent },
    { path: 'transfer', component: TransferComponent, canActivate: [DeletedGuardService] },
    { path: 'voting', component: VotingComponent, canActivate: [DeletedGuardService] },
    { path: 'vesting', component: VestingComponent, canActivate: [DeletedGuardService] }
  ] },
]
```

If you want to create a new account, you can do it as a '*logged in*' user and you'll have a full control of your child accounts or create a new one.
Difference is the parameter in the URL:
`https://baseurl.com/create-account/*accountName*` - creates child account
`https://baseurl.com/create-account` - creates new account

CreateAccount component acts as a wizard which uses **@ngrx/store** to handle wizard navigation. AccountName url parameter specifies different starting point in wizard.

CreateAccount module routes:

```
export const routes: Array<Route> = [
  { path: '', component: CreateAccountComponent, canDeactivate: [CreateAccountGuardService] },
  { path: ':account', component: CreateAccountComponent, canDeactivate: [CreateAccountGuardService] },
];
```

Before I refactored the project to use lazy loaded modules everything worked flawlessly. Now, with this configuration, no matter what URL I use I'm always redirected to root and **CreateAccountComponent** is shown.

`https://baseurl.com/*accountName*` -> `https://baseurl.com/`

`https://baseurl.com/*accountName*/transfer` -> `https://baseurl.com/`

`https://baseurl.com/create-account` -> `https://baseurl.com/`

`https://baseurl.com/create-account/*accountName*` -> `https://baseurl.com/`

How exactly can I differentiate between literal route `create-account` and parametrized route `:name`? Using `pathMatch: full` on various places didn't help at all. I must admit that my understanding of routing is still not very strong.

That's how route used to look like before refactor:

```
export const routes: Array<Route> = [
  { path: '', component: WelcomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'create-account', component: CreateAccountComponent, canDeactivate: [CreateAccountGuardService], pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'create-account/:account', component: CreateAccountComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canDeactivate: [CreateAccountGuardService] },
  { path: ':name', component: AccountComponent, canActivateChild: [AccountGuardService], children: [
    { path: '', component: OverviewComponent },
    { path: 'transfer', component: TransferComponent, canActivate: [DeletedGuardService] },
    { path: 'voting', component: VotingComponent, canActivate: [DeletedGuardService] },
    { path: 'vesting', component: VestingComponent, canActivate: [DeletedGuardService] }
  ] },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: ''}
];
```

**EDIT:**
Cause of the problem found in Routes.Module.ts. I forgot to remove module which is no longer imported but rather lazy-loaded (**CreateAccountModule**)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';

import { CreateAccountModule } from './create-account/create-account.module';

import { routes } from './routes';
import { WalletComponent } from './wallet/wallet.component';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    /*CreateAccountModule, - removing this import fixes the problem with routing override. Routing now works. */
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
  ],
  declarations: [
    WalletComponent, 
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class RoutesModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark without building a complete project but try changing the order of the routes to be like below (that is having the 'create-account' route before ':name" route.

```
export const routes: Array<Route> = [
{ path: '', component: WelcomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
{ path: 'create-account', loadChildren: './create-account/create-account.module#CreateAccountModule', pathMatch: 'full'},  
{ path: ':name', loadChildren: './account/account.module#AccountModule' },
{ path: '**', redirectTo: ''}
];
```

Comment: I did try that but there's no difference

Comment: Can you post your module.ts file where you are brining in these route.ts files?

Comment: Thanks for a point, I think I found a solution, at least partial. See the edit

Comment: Yes that was exactly where I was thinking the issue was going to be. Glad I could at least point you in the direction!